# c++ runtime issues

Tags: c++, runtime-error

Alright, so I'm running into an issue where the state isn't being added into the 2d array that I have set up (allStates). Below is the code for the addState function that is being called. allStates is a 10x10 array that should be empty until this point.

```
void addState(string stateName){
        for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
            for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                if (allStates[row][col].get_name().empty()){
                    allStates[row][col].set_values(stateName);
                    cout << allStates[row][col].get_name();
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }   
};
```

Below is the place in the code where the addState function is called.

```
while(!infile.eof() && infile.good()){
    infile >> command;
    cout << command;
    if (command == "addState"){
        string stateName;
        infile >> stateName;
        cout << "\n" << stateName;
        a.addState(stateName);
        cout << a.get_state(stateName).get_name();
    }
}
```

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

a is a type Area, which holds all of the functions including addState, deleteState, and the like. I was getting an error saying that I couldn't call those functions without an object, so I created the a variable to allow that.

allStates is initialized in the Area class with all of those functions.

EDIT2:

```
class Area{
State allStates[10][10];
public:
    void addState(string stateName){
        for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
            for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                if (allStates[row][col].get_name().empty()){
                    allStates[row][col].set_values(stateName);
                    cout << allStates[row][col].get_name();
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }   
    };
    State get_state(string name){
        for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
            for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == name)
                    return allStates[row][col];
            }   
        }
    };
    void deleteState(string name){
        for (int row=0; row<10; row++){
            for (int col=0; col<10; col++){
                string newest;
                newest.clear();
                if (allStates[row][col].get_name() == name)
                    allStates[row][col].set_values(newest);
            }   
        }
    };
};
```

There are some more functions in the class, but since the addState function is called first, I'm not sure if there are any issues with the others.

Comment: How and where is `allStates` declared?  What class is `a` an object of?  You need to add more details

Comment: As Atilla said, please explain. Is it a C array, a std::verctor, etc?

Comment: Edited to answer some of those questions.

Comment: Are you flushing `cout`? `"\n"` is not guaranteed to flush.

Comment: I just tried to use a flush, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: What type is `command`? If it is a `char[]` the `if` will never be true.

Comment: command is a string, but it is working to that point. The if is true at that point.

Answer (score 2):

```
allStates[row][col].get_name()
```

Did you value initialize allState? otherwise, i doubt there is no object in 2d array

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: But how would I do that with an object? Would I just create one object to assign to the whole array?

Comment: can u post more information about State? is it a class? or you typedef it?

Comment: If i am not wrong, allState is 2d array of string? then you could simply declare it string allState[10][10]; string is std class, so it will invoke default constructor. And then, you have onjects in you arrays.

Comment: allState is a 2d array of type State

Comment: oh, then your State class needs a constructor to initialize all the variables that get_name() needs

Comment: Creating that constructor breaks everything. I get tons of errors about the constructor being called incorrectly, when it isn't called anywhere.

Comment: State[10][10], calls constructor 100 times to fill out that 2d array. Its good news! the constructor needs no parameter list, and need to initialize variables and get_name() deals with. if get_name return var name, and you will need to initialize name = "" in constructor

Answer (score 1):

While I'm hoping to see more information on allstate, I can give you another tip you may or may not enjoy.

```
while(infile >> command) {
//code
}
```

When using a stream as a condition, it will check the stream for you and return bool as well as grabbing the value you're attempting to grab. It acts as both .eof() && .good(). It's also a good way to avoid reading in '\n' into an array,list, etc by accident.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll edit to add the initialization of allStates[][]

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to test whether or not is in fact getting inside of that if statement. I've never been comfortable using multiple method calls without parens, nor empty(), although in most cases there's nothing wrong with it.